# How to retrieve latitude and longitude of Google Maps android

Tags: android

How can I retrieve latitude and longitude of Google Maps data from my database and display it to the user on the map in android ?

I have a database mysql containing some fields as longitude and latitude.

What is the best way to do such?

Is it possible through a Volley library?

If there is an example of this, it is good to me

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can draw stuff in the onMapReady callback. You can create Markers, draw circles, draw polygons.

To add a marker just call:

```
LatLng point = new LatLng(exampleLat, exampleLng);
mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point));
```

Here is an example of how to draw a circle:

```
CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
    .center(new LatLng(lat, lng))
    .radius(radius)
    .fillColor(Color.RED)
    .strokeColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
Circle circle = mGoogleMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
```

Here is a Polygon:

```
PolygonOptions polygonalOptions = new PolygonOptions()
    .fillColor(Color.RED)
    .strokeColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
    .clickable(true);
for (List<Double> latLng : myPolygon.path) {
    LatLng point = new LatLng(latLng.get(0), latLng.get(1));
    polygonalOptions.add(point);
}
mGoogleMap.addPolygon(polygonalOptions);
```

PS: Writing from my phone sorry for any mistakes or formatting issues.

Comment: Hello brother / excuse me first, I am a new Android developer, but your answer is different from my question

Comment: From what I understood in your question is that you have a map, you have a few points in your MySQL Database and you want to show those points on a Google Map in your App? Did I get something wrong?